# Дублирование строк в таблицах html

Tags: javascript, html

Пишу скрипт, который парсит информацию из json-файла, получает строки, а потом должен выводить их в две таблицы.
Почему-то в результате строки в таблицах выводятся по два раза каждая.
Что я делаю не так?

код скрипта:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("table.result").html(function()
{
    $.getJSON("https://googledrive.com/host/0B_DBJR7l-jYgdFlkWkpkQzdMZFk", function(users)
    {
        var config=[
          {"floor":"1","right":["101","102","103","104","105","106","107","121","122","123","124","125"],"left":["108","109","110","111","112","113"]}, 
          {"floor":"2","right":["201","202","203","204","205","206","207","220","221","222","223","224"],"left":["208","209","210","211","212","213","214"]}, 
          {"floor":"3","right":["301","302","303","304","305","306","307"],"left":["308","309","310","311","312","313","314"]}, 
          {"floor":"4","right":["401","402","403","404","405","406","407","420","421","422","423","424"],"left":["408","409","410","411","412","413","414"]}, 
          {"floor":"5","right":["501","502","503","504","505","506","510"],"left":["408","410","412","413"]}
                ];


        var left,right;
        if (num==1){left=config[0].left;right=config[0].right;}
        if (num==2){left=config[1].left;right=config[1].right;}
        if(num==3){left=config[2].right;right=config[2].right;}
        if (num==4){left=config[3].left;right=config[3].right;}
        if (num==5){left=config[4].left;right=config[4].right;}

        ndata=new Date();
        hours=ndata.getHours();
        mins=ndata.getMinutes();
        for(var i=0;i<left.length;i++)
        {
            var n=[],b=-1;
             $.each(users, function(id, val)
             {  
                  if((hours==9) || ((hours==10) && (mins<=20)))
                  {
                       if(left[i]==val.auditorium && val.building=="Таллинская ул., д. 34" && val.beginLesson=="09:00"){
                       b++; 
                      n[b]={"auditorium":val.auditorium,"lecturer":val.lecturer,"group":val.group,"discipline":val.discipline};}
                  }

                 if (((hours==10)&&(mins>=30))||((hours==11)&&(mins<=50)))
                  {
                       if(left[i]==val.auditorium && val.building=="ул., д. 34" && val.beginLesson=="10:30"){
                       b++; 
                      n[b]={"auditorium":val.auditorium,"lecturer":val.lecturer,"group":val.group,"discipline":val.discipline};}
                  }

                  if (((hours==12)&&(mins>=10))||((hours==13)&&(mins<=30)))
                  {
                       if(left[i]==val.auditorium && val.building=="Таллинская ул., д. 34" && val.beginLesson=="12:10"){
                      b++; 
                      n[b]={"auditorium":val.auditorium,"lecturer":val.lecturer,"group":val.group,"discipline":val.discipline};}
                  }

                  if (((hours==13)&&(mins>=30))||(hours==14)||((hours==15)&&(mins==0)))
                  {
                       if(left[i]==val.auditorium && val.building=="Таллинская ул., д. 34" && val.beginLesson=="13:40"){
                      b++; 
                      n[b]={"auditorium":val.auditorium,"lecturer":val.lecturer,"group":val.group,"discipline":val.discipline};}
                  }

                  if (((hours==15)&&(mins>=10))||((hours==16)&&(mins<=30))) 
                 {
                       if(left[i]==val.auditorium && val.building=="Таллинская ул., д. 34" && val.beginLesson=="15:10"){
                       b++; 
                      n[b]={"auditorium":val.auditorium,"lecturer":val.lecturer,"group":val.group,"discipline":val.discipline};}
                  }
                  if (((hours==16)&&(mins>=40))||(hours==17)||((hours==18)&&(mins==00)))
                  {
                       if(left[i]==val.auditorium && val.building=="Таллинская ул., д. 34" && val.beginLesson=="16:40"){
                       b++; 
                      n[b]={"auditorium":val.auditorium,"lecturer":val.lecturer,"group":val.group,"discipline":val.discipline};}
                  }
                  if (((hours==18)&&(mins>=10))||((hours==19)&&(mins<=30)))
                  {
                       if(left[i]==val.auditorium && val.building=="Таллинская ул., д. 34" && val.beginLesson=="18:10"){
                       b++; 
                      n[b]={"auditorium":val.auditorium,"lecturer":val.lecturer,"group":val.group,"discipline":val.discipline};}
                  }

                  if (((hours==19)&&(mins>=40))||(hours==20)||((hours==21)&&(mins==00)))
                  {
                       if(left[i]==val.auditorium && val.building=="Таллинская ул., д. 34" && val.beginLesson=="19:40"){
                       b++; 
                      n[b]={"auditorium":val.auditorium,"lecturer":val.lecturer,"group":val.group,"discipline":val.discipline};}
                  }
             });
            }
             if(b>-1){
                    $(".result").append("<tr><td style='width: 20; text-align: left;'><div>" + n[0].group + "-" + n[0].auditorium + "<div></td>" +
                     "<td style='width: 100; text-align: center;'><div>" + n[0].discipline + "<div></td>" +
                    "<td style='width: 90; text-align: center;'>" + n[0].lecturer+ "</td></tr>");
                  }

    });
});
});
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
dayarray=new   Array("воскресенье","понедельник","вторник","среда","четверг","пятница","суббота")
montharray=new Array ("января","февраля","марта","апреля","мая","июня","июля","августа","сентября","октября","ноября","декабря")
ndata=new Date();
day=dayarray[ndata.getDay()];
month=montharray[ndata.getMonth()];
date=ndata.getDate();
year=ndata.getFullYear();
hours = ndata.getHours();
mins = ndata.getMinutes();
secs = ndata.getSeconds();
if (hours < 10) {hours = "0" + hours }
if (mins < 10) {mins = "0" + mins }
if (secs < 10) {secs = "0" + secs }
lesson = " ";
if ((hours==9)||((hours==10)&&(mins<=20))) {lesson = "1 пара"};
if (((hours==10)&&(mins>=30))||((hours==11)&&(mins<=50))) {lesson="2 пара"};
if (((hours==12)&&(mins>=10))||((hours==13)&&(mins<=30))) {lesson="3 пара"};
if (((hours==13)&&(mins>=40))||(hours==14)||((hours==15)&&(mins==0)))    {lesson="4 пара"};
if (((hours==15)&&(mins>=10))||((hours==16)&&(mins<=30))) {lesson="5 пара"};
if (((hours==16)&&(mins>=40))||(hours==17)||((hours==18)&&(mins==00))) {lesson="6 пара"};
if (((hours==18)&&(mins>=10))||((hours==19)&&(mins<=30))) {lesson="7 пара"};
if (((hours==19)&&(mins>=40))||(hours==20)||((hours==21)&&(mins==00))) {lesson="6 пара"};

if(lesson===" "){
datastr=(date + " " + month + " " + year + " " + day + " "+ hours + "." + mins );
}
else{
datastr=(date + " " + month + " " + year + " " + day + " "+ hours + "." + mins + " " + lesson);
}
</script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    num=3;
</script>
<div class = "page-contaner"> 
    <div class="square">
        <div class ="both">
            <div class ="date">
                <script language="JavaScript" charset="UTF-8">
                document.write(datastr);
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class ="floor">
                <script language="JavaScript" charset="UTF-8">
                document.write(num + " этаж");
                </script>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back_square"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="back_square2"></div>
</div>
<div class="table-style">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="result.js"> </script>
<table class="result" style = "width: 50%; height:200px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 0px solid grey; float:right;"> 
</table>
<table class="result" style = "width: 50%; height:200px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 0px solid grey; float:left;"> 
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: вставьте users объектом, json же не видно.

Comment: я могу дать ссылку на json-файл
https://googledrive.com/host/0B_DBJR7l-jYgdFlkWkpkQzdMZFk

Comment: так у вас таблицы идентифицируются одинаково - одним классом `.result`

Comment: если я там другой класс указываю, вообще ничего не выводится

Comment: @Jean-Claude
без class = "result" оно не работает, и в случае, если это вообще убрать, и в случае, если заменить на другой класс

Comment: короче у вас нет никакого разделения аудиторий направо/налево, тем более вложенные циклы `for( left.length) { $.each() }`  и почему здесь именно left.length, нет раздельной идентификации таблиц - коридор направо/налево, вы все данные тулите в обе таблицы

Comment: вам в массив `n` надо добавлять объекты с идентификацией таблицы, если left - в левую таблицу, если right - в правую таблицу.